# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error during approval process

Tags: visualforce, approval-process

I have a custom object where a user is approving or rejecting a record. The approval process is being done through a Visualforce page where the user clicks on the submit button and based on a picklist value, the record is either approved or rejected. I have a profile and I have 2 users assigned to that profile. When the first user clicks on the submit with the picklist value 'Approve', the record gets approved. But when the second user does the same, I get this error.

```
INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY
```

Both the users are the `Assigned Approver` and the OWD for the object is `Public Read/Write`. So what is going wrong here?

Comment: I was running into something similar about 2 weeks ago. It turned out that I was trying to approve a record that had already been approved (and had thus exited my approval process). Are you testing the approval with the second user on the same record? If the users in your profile are `user1` and `user2`, do you always test approving with `user1` first? What happens if you test approving with `user2` first (does the approval for `user1` then generate the same error)? Does your approval process end after any approver approves?